# How do I speed up incredibly slow iteration through pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have collected 500ms stock data for several weeks. No I am wanting to go through each days data an iterate through it to determine at any given last price value, how many times a specific lowerbound would be passed followed by a specific upperbound being passed for the rest of the day. The lowerbound has to be passed before the script starts searching for whether the upperbound will be reached.

So essentially if the last price at row i is 10 and the lowerbound then is 9 and 11. The code will first try to find a moment when the remaining rows i+1...i+2... are reach the lowerbound, as soon as the lower bound is reached the code switches into looking for when the upperbound is reached. If the upperbound is reached then the success will add 1 and the code starts looking for the lowerbound again, doing this whole process again.

This entire process occurs for every single row, so essentially for each row we will have a column for how many times a successful lower and upper bound reach occurred in the rows following that given row.

The problem I am having is that I have about 14400 rows per day, and about 40 days so around 576000 rows of data. The iteration takes absolutely forever, and in order for me to do this across all of my data I will need my computer to run a few days. Surely I am not doing this in the most efficient way possible am I? Can anybody maybe point to a concept that I can rewrite this code in a much more effective way? Or am I just stuck waiting for ever for it to prepare my data?

```
    range_per = .00069 #the percentage determining lower and upper bound
    data['Success?']=np.nan
    data['Success? Count']=np.nan

    #For every row count how many times the trade in the range would be successful
    for i in range(0,len(data)):
        last_price = data.at[i,'lastPrice']
        lower_bound = last_price -  last_price*range_per
        upper_bound = last_price + last_price*range_per
        lower_bound_reached = False
        upper_bound_reached = False
        success=0

        for b in range(i+1,len(data)):
            last_price = data.at[b,'lastPrice']
            while lower_bound_reached == False:
                if lower_bound - last_price >=0:
                    upper_bound_reached = False
                    lower_bound_reached = True

                else:
                    break
            while (upper_bound_reached == False and lower_bound_reached ==True):
                if upper_bound - last_price <=0:
                    success+=1
                    lower_bound_reached = False
                    upper_bound_reached = True


                else:
                    break
        print('row %s: %s times' %(i, success))
        data['Success? Count'][i] = success
        if success>0:
            data['Success?'][i] = True
        else: 
            data['Success?'][i] = False
```

[image: Here a a look at the last price row and the two output rows created by the code above]

Comment: Don't work on individual rows at a time. The key to using Pandas (and NumPy etc) is doing things vectorised, working on full rows (or columns) at once.

Comment: so, near the top, you would have `lower_bound = data['lastPrice'] * (1-range_per)`.

Comment: It requires some rethinking of your code (due to the if-else bloks), but then your code becomes much faster.

Comment: might be easier to answer if you give sample data and expected output

Comment: can you show your sample data and sample output? I think from reading your code it could be optimised into a few lines./

Comment: Added a screenshot of some of the data. The first column is the last price column and the last two columns are those created by the code I shared. I couldn't work on the full column at once because for a lower bound and upper bound for each row depends on the values that occur afterwards. So for a row i, the following rows will be checked first for a lower bound reach, and only if the lower bound was reached will it begin checking for whether the upper bound will be reached. So for example in row 2131, it occurred 3 times that the lower and upper bound were reached in the succeeding rows.